# NSInternalInconsistencyException TableViewCell Unit Test

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to perform unit tests on a table view. I want to test a function that relies on selecting a particular cell, which is why I am trying to fetch the cell at an `IndexPath` and then `setSelected`.

I am running into this error when calling `dequeueReusableCell()`:

> caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException", "unable to dequeue a cellID with identifier cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard"

```
func testCellFunction() {

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)

    let cell = myViewController.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellID", for: indexPath)

    cell.setSelected(true, animated: false)

    // Processing that relies on cell being selected

    cell.setSelected(false, animated: false)
}
```

Running the normal program in ios works. However the unit test fails.

Comment: During normal operation, how is your cell connected to your table?  During your test, how is `myViewController` instantiated?

Comment: During normal operation I use `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` and during the test i instantiate as follows: `let myViewController = MyViewController()`, where `class MasterViewController : UITableViewController, DetailViewControllerDelegate`

Comment: `MyViewController()`, that's not initializating your MyViewController instance with its Storyboard/Xib.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Fixed it with `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)`
        `let myViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController") as! MyViewController`